# Clases/Methods/Attributes Javascript Error

Tags: javascript

I have this class.

```
function cnv(){
   this.attribute1;
}
```

So i need that, when i do this :

```
var c = new cnv();

c.attribute1 = 'rojo';
```

If i make some change in my aatributes, for exammple aatribute1, this call some method:

```
cnv.prototype.method1 = function (){
    ...code
}
```

So basically i need to know if when i change some atribute in my class, this change can call to some function as method, thanks ;)

```
if -->> c.attribute1 = 'blue'   -->> then(beacuase of change on attr) -->> method1
```

Comment: You're looking for getters and setters.

Comment: as @Bergi said you need to provide getters and setters. These are some methods that you use to access or modify the value of the attributes of object. If you always use a setter to modify a value, you will be able to control the way that is modified. It's a good practice in the object oriented programming. Check this: http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2013/12/es5-getters-setters/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `observe` function of Javascript.

Follow the below example code:

```
var model = {};
Object.observe(model, function(changes){
    changes.forEach(function(change) {
        console.log(change.type, change.name, change.oldValue);
    });
});
```

Comment: It's just a pitty that Object.observe is RIP, see here: https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/es-discuss/2015-November/044684.html or here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe

Comment: i cant undestand this :S

Comment: can you explain me how call this function or execute,? thanks

Comment: I think this link http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es7/observe/ help you to understand that in a better way. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the Object.defineProperty and create custom getters/setters for your objects. In the example below, you see a simple observable class that accepts an array of properties you wish to watch, and that calls the changed method when the value of an observed property changes.

It is simply as an example class here, so that I could show the principle of it :) Feel free to change it as you like

(ps: I updated the code a bit, so it reacts on keypress, and you see the changes that are given through ;))

```js
function Observable(props) {
  if (!this instanceof Observable) 
    return new Observable(props);
  
  var values = {}, define = function(target, propName, propHolder) {
      Object.defineProperty(target, propName, {
        get: function() {
          return propHolder[propName];
        },
        set: function(value) {
          if (value === propHolder[propName]) {
            return;
          } 
          var oldValue = propHolder[propName];
          propHolder[propName] = value;
          if (target.changed && target.changed.apply) {
            target.changed.apply(target, [propName, oldValue, value]);
          }
        },
        configurable: false
      });
  };
  
  if (props) {
    for (var i = 0, len = props.length; i < len; i++) {
      define(this, props[i], values);
    }
  }
    
  this.changed = function(property, oldValue, newValue) {
    // this changed
    var el = document.getElementById('log');
    if (el) {
      el.innerHTML += '<p><b>' + property + '</b>: Changed from <i>' + oldValue + '</i> to <i>' + newValue + '</i></p>';
    }
    console.log(property + ' changed from ' + oldValue + ' to ' + newValue);
  }
}
  
var model = new Observable(['value']);

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  // demonstrating the changes
  model.value = 'test';
  model.value = 'sample';
  model.value = '';
});

function update(sourceElement) {
  var att = sourceElement.getAttribute('data-id'),
      mod = sourceElement.getAttribute('data-model');
  
  window[mod][att] = sourceElement.value;
}
```

```html
<input id="item" type="text" onkeyup="update(this);" onchange="update(this);" data-id="value" data-model="model" />
<div id="log">
</div>
```

Comment: im not talking about change on a input, its a change just for console for example

Comment: @AlbertoAcuña In my example it doesn't really matter, if you would change `model.value = 'test';` it would also print out to the console, I just added it as an example so you could see the changes easily enough. I also added an example what happens if you just assign things to it

Answer (score 0):

I make it work using just a method that change everything to the other class, inside of framerequest animation, thanks everyone btw.

Note: Object.observe doesn't work in all navegators :'( .. @Achu